# node.js express ajax sessions

Tags: ajax, node.js

i am having an issue with express and ajax sessions. My application receives requests through Ajax (POST & GET) and sets up a session variable. While sessions work fine if the request doesn't come from ajax, in the opposite case they just don't work. For example :

```
if (typeof req.session.id == 'undefined'){
req.session.id = 1;
```

}

```
else {
req.session.id++;
 } 
res.send({session:req.session.id});
```

now when i do localhost:3000/ all is well, it increments every time. If i do the same from angular via $http i keep getting 1. i tried the same in PHP just in case there's something wrong with angular but it works just fine. Please note that the ajax call comes from localhost:80

My express setup :

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('secret'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:'mySecret'}));
app.use(express.session({store:new express.session.MemoryStore(),maxAge : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)}));
app.use(app.router)
```

EDIT

by doing console.log(req); i noticed that when not coming from AJAX i get :

```
 cookies:
```

{ PHPSESSID: 'jm2p2kn7etmofrp48s8sv4pu47',
    ZDEDebuggerPresent: 'php',
    '': 'phtml',
    user_admin: 'MTUzOnJvb3Q6U2ptaHJpZmllaG8=',
    'connect.sess': 's:j:{"id":7}.oIAoC356/z4fQ++iH44N7YxWZWEP49bTHp1h/gpAElY'
    }

but when coming from AJAX i get {}

Comment: As far as I know, node / express don't differentiate between XHR/non-XHR requests unless you explicitly change something. If you post the code for your ajax route, that may help diagnose the problem.

Comment: the problem was in the port, in order for it to work properly i had to set the withCredentials flag to true on the ajax call. Then on the server side, i had to add res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true'); and all is well.

Answer (score 7):

on node.js :

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

on ajax :

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: What exactly does this do?